# How to change color of a container border using radio buttons using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue, I need to create a settings dropdown menu when you can select different themes. The themes have to change the background color and border color, I have the background color working, however I'm struggling to make the border change color.

```js
function changeTheme() {
  if (document.getElementById("theme1").checked = true) {
    document.container.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    document.container.style.borderColor = "red";
  }
}

function bgcolor(color, border) {
  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.body.style.borderColor = border;

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="theme" value="1" onclick="bgcolor('lightgray', 'red');" onchange="showFeedback('You changed the theme!')">Light<br><br>
</div>
```

So the container is a square in the middle of the page with a border. When I select one of the themes the background color of the whole page should change and the border color of the container in the middle should change as well.
I tried `onclick="changeTheme()`but it doesn't work

Comment: can you add html fragment where you have **changeTheme()**?

Comment: Yes, I understood. Can you update your question in order to add more html?

Comment: I don't use changeTheme() anywhere in html, The color is changed by the **onclick="bgcolor**

Comment: So... that changes the border color for the `body`, not the radio button...

Comment: You need to set the `border` property, like `1px solid red`, else it won't have a visible width :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tyblitz remarked: your "border" needs to be set properly:

```js
function changeTheme() {
  if (document.getElementById("theme1").checked = true) {
    document.container.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    document.container.style.borderColor = "red";
  }
}

function bgcolor(color, border) {
  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.body.style.border = border;

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="radio" id="theme1" 
   name="theme" value="1" 
   onclick="bgcolor('lightgray', '6px solid red');"
   onchange="console.log('You changed the theme!')">Light<br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: But really, you shouldn't be using JS to set style properties in the slightest: set a class. `container.classList.add('red-and-grey')`, and _most certainly_ don't use `on...` bindings in the HTML code, it's not 1998 anymore. Use normal `addEventListener(...)` on the JS side. The HTML shouldn't need to know _anything_ about what JS needs to run. Have a look at Scott's answer, which is much better advice for modern browsers.

Comment: Yes, definitely! I agree with Mike. I posted the above mainly to illustrate to OP the use of the built in SO snippets and that a small fix would make his particular code work. But the approach itself is not a good one. Look at Scott's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

To set a border, you must specify the thickness and style.

Also, don't use inline styles or inline event handlers. Just set a pre-existing class upon the event. And instead of checking to see if the radio button is selected, just use the `click` event of the button. If you've clicked it, it's selected.

Lastly, if you are using a form field, but only as a UI element and not to actually submit data anywhere, you don't need the `name` attribute.

```js
document.getElementById("theme1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.classList.add("lightTheme");  
});
```

```css
.lightTheme { border:1px solid red; background-color:lightgrey; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="radio" id="theme1" value="1">Light<br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**2nd Edit :**
(*Thanks to Scott Marcus answer and Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans comment*)

[Here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/OJLXQRy) is a pen for it.
I create classes for each theme with the naming pattern : prefix "colorTheme" followed by the input value attribute's value.

```
function themeChange() {
    /* theme class naming pattern : prefix "colorTheme"
     followed by the input "value attribute" 's value */
    var themeCheckedClassValue = "colorTheme" + this.value;

    /* don't do anything if we click on the same input/label */
    if (themeCheckedClassValue != document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass) {

      document.body.classList.remove(document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass);
      document.body.classList.add(themeCheckedClassValue);
      /* new current theme value stored in data-current-theme-class custom 
         attribut of body */
      document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass = themeCheckedClassValue;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    /* querySelector and if statement only needed at DOMContentLoaded
       So I did a seperate function for this event */
    var themeChecked = document.querySelector('input[id^="theme"]:checked');
    if (themeChecked) {
        var themeCheckedClassValue = "colorTheme" + themeChecked.value;
        document.body.classList.add(themeCheckedClassValue);
        document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass = themeCheckedClassValue;
    }
    else {
        /* if there is no input with the attribute "checked"
        the custom attribut data-current-theme-class takes the value "null" */
        document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass = null;
    }
});

/* input[id^="theme] mean every input with an id starting with "theme" */
var themeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="theme"]');

for (let i = 0; i < themeInputs.length; i++) {
    themeInputs[i].addEventListener("click", themeChange);
}
```

This way you can simply add new themes by following the same naming pattern.

```js
function themeChange() {
  /* theme class naming pattern : prefix "colorTheme"
     followed by the input "value attribute" 's value */
  var themeCheckedClassValue = "colorTheme" + this.value;

  /* don't do anything if we click on the same input/label */
  if (themeCheckedClassValue != document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass) {

    document.body.classList.remove(document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass);
    document.body.classList.add(themeCheckedClassValue);
    /* new current theme value stored in data-current-theme-class custom 
       attribut of body */
    document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass = themeCheckedClassValue;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* querySelector and if statement only needed at DOMContentLoaded
     So I did a seperate function for this event */
  var themeChecked = document.querySelector('input[id^="theme"]:checked');
  if (themeChecked) {
    var themeCheckedClassValue = "colorTheme" + themeChecked.value;
    document.body.classList.add(themeCheckedClassValue);
    document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass = themeCheckedClassValue;
  } else {
    /* if there is no input with the attribute checked
    the custom attribut data-current-theme-class takes the value "null" */
    document.body.dataset.currentThemeClass = null;
  }
});

/* input[id^="theme] mean every input with an id starting with "theme" */
var themeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="theme"]');

for (let i = 0; i < themeInputs.length; i++) {
  themeInputs[i].addEventListener("click", themeChange);
}
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input,
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

.colorTheme1 {
  color: rgb(36, 36, 33);
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: rgb(248, 236, 220);
  border-color: rgb(60, 75, 124);
}

.colorTheme2 {
  background-color: rgb(39, 34, 28);
  border-color: rgb(102, 102, 153);
  color: rgb(248, 236, 220);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.colorTheme3 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" id="theme1" name="theme" value="1" checked><label for="theme1">Light</label></li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="theme" value="2"><label for="theme2">Dark</label></li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="theme" value="3"><label for="theme3">Flashy</label></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: if you can have multiple color themes set, something probably went wrong? It's better to make sure you know which theme is active on the JS side using a `currentTheme` value, so you don't have to unset "however many themes there are". Or, don't set the class, but also set `element.dataset.currentThemeClass = ...` so you can refer to that in your remove: `element.classlist.remove(element.dataset.currentThemeClass);`

Comment: You can't have multiple color themes set, but yes I see the logic and you are right. Thank you for taking the time (JS beginner here), I will do an edit.

Comment: @Mike I did the edit. If you have a minute and see anything else I can improve, I would be happy to learn something new!

Comment: if you place your `<script>` at the end of `<body>`, or you put it in the `<head>` with the `defer` keyword, you don't need to wait for DOMContentLoaded. In both cases, all DOM elements will already exist by the time your script runs.